# Arduino with multiple DC Motors and Servo Motors

Tags: arduino, robotics

I am new in robotic but an old gunney in software engineering.
I two questions about Arduino/Robotic. I have an Arduino UNO R4 WIFI.

Is it possible to connect three DC Motors and two or three servo motors on the arduino?
The Arduino and two of the dc motors (cheap motors) and the servo motors should use power from one power source (batteries) and the third dc motors (more powertfull) should use another power source (other batteries) but all of them should be controllable by arduino?

If its possible, how? What do I need for all this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need PWM channels to control motors and servos. When we look in the DS for the used processor, it says the following:

> The General PWM Timer (GPT) is a 32-bit timer with two GPT32 channels, and a 16-bit timer with six GPT16 channels.
> PWM waveforms can be generated by controlling the up-counter, down-counter, or the up- and down-counter. In
> addition, PWM waveforms can be generated for controlling brushless DC motors. The GPT can also be used as a
> general-purpose timer.

It follows that you have a total of 8 separate PWM channels available. Is it enough for your project? You have to judge that for yourself. I also don't know if the board makes all PWM channels available, but I'm guessing that it does.

Edit:
The documentation for the board says that 6 PWM channels are accessible.

More details about the PWM and the processor can be obtained from the [manufacturer's DS](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/mah/renesas-ra4m1-group-users-manual-hardware?r=1054146&#page=387)